# Stop Interarrival time of the source ,when the quee is full , and re-activate the source when the quee has space

Tags: java, anylogic

I am doing a basic design with a source+quee+delay+sink. The idea is to create 1 agent per day for example and have a maximum capacity of 5 in the quee, at the moment that the quee reaches its maximum I would like to stop the source until the delay finishes and space is released. At this point the source should continue producing agents.

I tried to do this using the ratio arrival and the function:set_ratio(0), but that is not exactly what I want because the agents are not created in 1 per day as in interarrival time.

Any tips on how to approach this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply turn off "forced pushing" in the source properties. Then, you can decide what to do with the agents created while the downstream queue was full:
[image]

Comment: Hi Benjamin, thank you for your fast response. Now is working the way I wanted to.

Thanks!

Comment: Great. Please upvote answers that where helpful, helps others with similar issues in the future, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote